# Deployment error on a VF page. Page Popup does not exist

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment

Have you seen anytime an error **" Page Popup does not exist"** while `deploying the VF page`

. I haven't seen it before and unable to clearly understand what exactly is the issue. Also,There is no popup code on this page,that I could expect this error.
Please assist what are the possible reason for such error

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The error means you have a hard reference to a page called `popup`. This might be in your Apex code as `Page.popup`, or in your Visualforce code, written as `{!$Page.popup}` or, more likely, `{!URLFOR($Page.popup,...)}`. You'll need to do a search in your code for this hard reference. You will either need to remove the reference, or, more likely, deploy the `popup` page as well as any related components, Apex code, static resources, etc.

Comment: thank for reverting. As i have mentioned in my post the page doesn't call any popup. And am still copping across this issue. Am not sure if earlier the vf had the reference and its been removed from page, but post removal internally vf is still having a reference in its memory/cache.

Comment: @user10727 no, the reference could be in a controller somewhere, maybe a unit test? You definitely have a reference somewhere, you just need to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is sorted,sharing for reference as I dint find anything on this issue on internet.
As suggested by sfdcfox,if a popup reference is there we need to find, and fix it.

On other hand, like in our case VF was not having any Popup reference so alternative option we took was to create a NEW Page and paste the code from old vf having issue. This worked well in our case, and we could deploy without any issue.